# Ball object slows down without gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D Block breaker game; the issue is that my ball will slow down after a while, yet there isn't any gravity and the bounciness is at 100% so it should keep all its kinetic energy. I just need the ball to stay at a constant speed.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

    public Paddle paddle;
    private Vector3 paddleToBallVector;
    private bool Started = false;

    void Start () {
        paddleToBallVector = this.transform.position 
        paddle.transform.position;
        print(paddleToBallVector);
        //this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().drag = 0f;
    }   

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (!Started) { 
            this.transform.position = paddle.transform.position + paddleToBallVector;
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Debug.Log("mouse clicked, Started = " + Started);
                Started = true;
                this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(2f, 10f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you change the method name from Update to FixedUpdate?

Comment: I just hoped that it might help with the physics, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: The names are important. Update is called automatically when every frame loads. Changing its name will prevent it from working - it basically means it will not be called at all.

Comment: I changed it back to Update and like I said, nothing changed; it slows down all the same.

Comment: I actually worked on the same game, and it worked well for me when I changed the gravity. There's a way to do it for the ball or for the entire project setup. It's a bit complex so I'll put it in an answer below with pictures. Just give me about 15 minutes to write it up.

Comment: The answer with screen grabs is below. If it solves your issue - could you accept it? Just click on the gray check mark next to it, making it green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ball to have constant velocity, you could set it each frame in `Update`

```
myRigidbody.velocity = speed * (myRigidbody.velocity.normalized);
```

Where `myRigidBody` is a private `RigidBody` declared somewhere in your script, and set in `Start()` like this

```
myRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Because you dont want to have to call `GetComponent` every single frame.

Comment: I tried this but it was unfortunately outdated so I can't use it, currently I'm looking for the updated version on how to do this and the unity manual isn't being very helpful.

Comment: Ahh.. I didnt mean that you should use MonoBehaviour.rigidbody... ill update answer

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked just fine, my only problem was that I had to use GetComponent every single frame instead of myRigidbody. Under Start I tried:    var myRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
And under Update I tried:
    this.myRigidbody.velocity = speed * (myRigidbody.velocity.normalized); I ended up using GetComponent instead of myRigidbody, I hope I made that clear... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't in the code - it's in the game Gravity settings. You could solve it in one of two ways:

1) change the gravity scale of the ball - go to the ball game object or Prefab, and look at the RigidBody2D component. In there, you have a field called "Gravity Scale", usually set to 1. Changing it to 0.1 will make your ball light and quick. However, this setup isn't ideal for a game with multiple levels.
[image: Gravity Scale on the Ball]

2) Change the global gravity in the project settings. Go in the Edit Menu to the Project Settings and in the menu choose Physics2D:

[image: Project Settings Physics2D]

In the panel that is opened you usually have a realistic gravity scale of -9.81. Change it to something like -1. 
[image]
This will make all the objects in your game light, and lessen the hold of gravity for all levels. In a brick-breaker type game when only the ball is loose and thrown around, it makes the most sense.

Comment: Well I already did this part which is why I'm so confused. There's no gravity and the bounciness is set to 1.

Comment: Double check that you have the physic material correctly applied to the ball, and that the project setting is set as I described and that You're not setting things in game mode.

Answer (score 0):

Create a physics material 2D. Keep the bounciness at 1 but reduce the friction to zero. Now attach that material to your Ball Collider. Your ball won't lose any speed when colliding now

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29963174)